# Stack Overflow bounty did not lead to useful answer, but was not refunded 

Tags: support, stack-overflow, bounties, specific-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I placed a bounty on [AudioQueueFreeBuffer warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860988/audioqueuefreebuffer-warning). I didn't get any valid answers — I did get one answer that wasn't helpful — and simply lost my 50 reputation points. Will those points be given back to me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, bounties are not refunded, even if no answers were posted. The purpose of the bounty system is like advertising—even if no one buys the product, you must pay for the advertisement.

Comment: but then the name bounty is misleading, since when no one catches a criminal, you don't have to pay anyone

Comment: This is a good point.  I was confused by this as well. Can it be renamed?

Answer (score 1):

No. Bounties are not refunded once offered to a question. The reason is to encourage people who really are looking for answers to their questions. If bounties were to be refunded, it would've encouraged people to just offer bounties for all questions making the Bounty system not so useful at all.